# How do you return a value from one class method to another when using Q/promises/asynchronous functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, q

What is the best way to return a value from one class method to a different class method when using Q/promises/asynchronous functions?

Specifically, I have the following where ClassOne.myMethod() will call ClassTwo.test() to perform several asynchronous tasks (db updates, file writes, etc).  I would like ClassTwo.test() to return something (in this example, "FOUR").  How do I do that when using promises and asynchronous calls?

I am doing this because I want ClassTwo to be a very generic set of methods that perform tasks that will be called by other classes (as not to reinvent the wheel each time).

E.g.,

```
var myClass = new ClassTwo();

ClassOne.prototype.myMethod = function(myClass) {
  console.log('Returns: ', myClass.test());        
};


ClassTwo.prototype.test = function() {

  var one = function() {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    console.log('ONE');
    deferred.resolve();
    return deferred.promise;
  };

  var two = function() {
    var deferred = Q.defer();    
    console.log('TWO');
    deferred.resolve();
    return deferred.promise;
  };

  var three = function() {  
    var deferred = Q.defer();    
    console.log('THREE');
    deferred.resolve();
    return 'FOUR';    
  };

  return one()
      .then(two)
      .then(three);

};
```

Comment: You can pass values when you resolve the promise, as in `deferred.resolve('something', 'else');`

Comment: Thanks, Adeneo.  Your comment, in addition to Mike's below, are what I needed to understand how to implement this.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like the following. Note that I have wrapped all the calls to deferred.resolve() into callbacks from asynchronous functions (in this case process.nextTick), since that would be a more realistic use case then resolving the promise before returning it, and is, I assume what you would be doing with your asynchronous tasks. Also you declare a variable 'myClass' and also use the same identifier as a function parameter for 'myMethod'.I don't think that is really what you meant to do, so I have changed that in my example below.

```
var ClassTwo = function() {};
var ClassOne = function() {};
var Q = require('q');

ClassOne.prototype.myMethod = function(myClass) {
  myClass.test().then(function(result) { // now test returns a promise
      console.log('returns '+ result);   // that we call .then() on
  });
};


ClassTwo.prototype.test = function() {

    var one = function() {
        var deferred = Q.defer();
        console.log('ONE');
        process.nextTick(function() { deferred.resolve()});
        return deferred.promise;
    };

    var two = function() {
        var deferred = Q.defer();
        console.log('TWO');
        process.nextTick(function() { deferred.resolve()});
        return deferred.promise;
    };

    var three = function() {
      var deferred = Q.defer();
      console.log('THREE');
      process.nextTick(function() { deferred.resolve('FOUR')});
      return deferred.promise;
   };

    return one()
        .then(two)
        .then(three)
};

(new ClassOne()).myMethod(new ClassTwo());
```

Comment: Thanks, Mike.  This is the answer I was looking for.  Your response was very helpful, timely, and easy to understand.